# Stories by Philip Jose Farmer set in the universe of "The Lovers"

Tags: philip-jose-farmer

The novel *The Lovers* (1961) and the novella *Rastignac the Devil* (1954) are set in a universe that has this fictional story:

- Earth suffers a biological apocalypse that is about to wipe out the human race.
- The few survivors belong to isolated minority races that spread throughout the world, such as Icelanders and Samoans.
- A small remnant of French people survive in their original realm but are soon overrun by the newly expanding peoples. Facing assimilation or extinction, a group of French build six interstellar ships and travel to other stars.
- Many years later, these people have settled on another planet where they share the land and some kind of symbiosis with two sentient alien races. This is the planet where "Rastignac the Devil" takes place. In the end, a group of dissident humans manage to go to the ancient interstellar ships, which were stranded in orbit, and flee to some other star.
- Some decades later, one of the dominant cultures on Earth, the Haijacks, a nasty totalitarian and oppressive religious sect, sends an expedition from Earth to another planet different from the previous one. This planet is dominated by a species of intelligent pseudo-insects with a technological advancement equivalent to the early 20th century. This is where "The Lovers" takes place.
- On this new planet one of the Haijakcs who is, or is soon to be, a hidden dissident of their cult, meets a very human-looking alien woman who speaks in an evolved dialect of French and claims to be the daughter of Rastignac and a humanoid alien woman native to this planet. (The Lovers)

Are there any other Philip Jose Farmer stories set in this universe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ISFDb lists [*The Lovers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11928) (1961) and "[Rastignac the Devil](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63233)" (1954) as elements of a series titled [*The Sturch*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?24703).  The other listed story is "[Moth and Rust](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?114165)" (1953) which was novelized as [*A Woman a Day*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?114165) (1960) and has the alternate titles *The Day of the Timestop* and *Timestop!*.

The novel *The Lovers* is (per ISFDb and the [Science Fiction Encyclopedia](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/farmer_philip_jose)) an expansion of an [earlier 1952 novella](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?80098) of the same name first published in *Startling Stories*.  (His first published work and a Hugo award winner.)

Note that SF Encyclopedia observes "[*A Woman a Day*] was billed as a sequel to *The Lovers* but bore little relation to the earlier story."